# Deploy angular 2 systemjs

Tags: angular, deployment

I have created an angular 2 application with MVC. I did not create the application as angular-cli or webpack. I am using visual studio 2015, so what will be the easy way to bundle and minify my project without making significant changes? do I have to use angularcli/gulp or webpack to d that?

here is my file structure(note my ts file under script folder):

[image]

Script folder
[image]

Comment: Rollup can be a good tool for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-rollup

Comment: yes, but this will require angular-cli and karma? is there a away to bundle/minify files without it!

Comment: no angular-cli needed, no karma neither, as karma is for tests.

Comment: You can look at some online available tutorial like https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/09/18/angular-2-aot-compiler-and-tree-shaking-with-webpack2-and-or-rollup-step-by-step.aspx